Sufficiency for Sup (C) = Sup(A) + Sup(B)
This came from my last week's midterm exam problem.
This Course is Advanced Calculus/Introduction to Analysis, and the textbook is Apostol's.
My professor asked us to:

Prove if the claim is believed to be True.


Give counterexample if the claim is believed to be False.


Claim:

Given nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$, 
let $C$ = { $x+y:x \in A,\text{ } y \in B$ }.


Then, $\mathit {sup}$ $C$ = $\mathit {sup}$ $A$ $+$ $\mathit {sup}$ $B$

My thoughts:

Since $A$ and $B$ aren't said to be $\pmb{bounded}$, this claim is not, generally, True.

My answer:

False, counterexample given as follow. 
let $A$ $=$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ $=$ {$1$}. 
Clearly, $\mathit {sup}$ $B$ $=$ $1$. 
But, since $\mathbb{R}$ isn't bounded,  $\mathit {sup}$ $A$ doesn't exist at all. 
Therefore, $\mathit {sup}$ $C$ would not exist, too.  (How could $1$ be added to something that don't exist)

Correct Answer: True 

Both TA and Prof. respond that $\mathbb {R}$ itself is bdd above by $+\infty$

My understanding and confusion:

I know and can prove the theorem, which explicitly state that all subsets must have supremum, hence, implicitly implying bounded, and is a bit different from the claim above.


I know for extended $\mathbb{R}$, denoted as $\mathbb{R}^*$ in textbook,  $\mathit{sup} 
\text{ }(\mathbb{R}^*)$ does exist and is $+\infty$ 


Isn't supremum for any real (sub)set must be a real number?
---   Not saying that supremum must be in this (sub)set, that would be, if exists, maximum. 
If True, how can $\infty$ be supremum of $\mathbb{R}$? (Contrast to it being not real, mathematically and per se )

Also, since the answer is True,

does that mean the theorem doesn't actually need "being bounded" as its sufficient condition?

Please enlighten me, appreciate for any help.

What is your definition of supremum?

I am not aware there exist different definition for supremum, as I am quite new to Math. But from what I've learnt, a number # is said to be a supremum of a set S must satisfy two conditions, a) # is an upper bound for S; b) no number less than # is an upper bound for S.

Formally speaking, there is no $+\infty$ upper bound because we're not dealing with the extended real numbers. However, I think, you can assume in this question that $A$ and $B$ are bounded for the sake of learning, for otherwise there is nothing interesting on it.

@Paulo Estêvão
I totally understand where you come from and no mean to cause a dispute, but since bdd isn't given, how can I simply assume it as being given, in exam or not? There isn't any other given statement that is equivalent to. For instance, it's not that both sets are said to be compact, and thus I can find out it is bounded, by compact imply closed and bdd.

Oh sorry, I thought that was an exercise that he passed, not an question of the exam. In this case you're completly right, for $+\infty$ isn't a real number and it can't be an upper bound of anything.

This question is not about General Topology or Number Theory. Please, choose the tags carefully.

@jjagmath     Appreciate your comment, and it indeed isn't about Number Theory, done changing it. But why isn't it about general topology? As Euclidean space is a special case of metric space. Or, there exists some gap between metric space and general topology that I yet to learn?

One usually allows for $\sup A=\infty$. If this convention is not followed in your class, then you would be right. The course staff's response suggests that this convention is followed in your course.

Yes, there is a gap between metric space and general topology. This is the description of the general-topology tag: "Everything involving general topological spaces: generation and description of topologies; open and closed sets, neighborhoods; interior, closure; connectedness; compactness; separation axioms; bases; convergence: sequences, nets and filters; continuous functions; compactifications; function spaces; etc. Please use the more specific tags, (algebraic-topology), (differential-topology), (metric-spaces), (functional-analysis) whenever appropriate."

@jjagmath Oddly enough, while the (analysis) tag uses the word "instead" to emphasize it shouldn't be used when a more specific tag applies, (general-topology) doesn't include that language.  I have previously interpreted it to mean the more specific tag is used in addition to (general-topology) when they are appropriate.

That said, @RayW, I would argue neither of the more general tags apply.  Nothing in your question deals with the tools introduced to deal with topology or metric spaces in general.  The tag system becomes significantly less useful if we apply every tag that sits above the topic.  At most general, your question is about ordered spaces, but it's sufficient to only tag it (real-analysis) and (supremum-and-infimum).

@BrianMoehring I agree. I think a good rule of thumb could be "Does the question make sense in that general context?". Talking about supremum and sum doesn't make sense in a general metric space, so even the metric-spaces tag is inadequate.

If you are assume your space is $\mathbb R^*$ then, no, the sup of set of real numbers does not need to be a real number any more then the sup of a set of rational numbers needs to be rational.  $+\infty > x$ for any real number so $+\infty$ is certainly an upper bound of $\mathbb R$.  And if $w<+\infty$ then either $w \in \mathbb R$ or $w=-\infty$.  In either case there exist $x\in \mathbb R$ so that $x > w$.  So $w$ is not a lower bound.  So $\sup \mathbb R = +\infty$

"I know and can prove the theorem, which explicitly state that all subsets must have supremum"  If you believe this, and I am quoting you directly, then you must believe $\sup \mathbb R$ must exist.

@fleablood
Ummm... what I mean in that is by the theorem given in Apostol's, it stated that for sup C = sup A + sup B to be true, A and B are assumed to have supremum, and if I don't know whether a set has a sup, how can the claim be true?

There are some vacuous true/false issues.  Is "The Loch Ness monster's diet consisits of every thing the Yeti's diet does" true or false?  I'd claim it's either meaningless or vacuously true.  What about "The Loch Ness monster eats what the yeti does".  I'd say that's more likely false but still... I'd think if a question mentions $\sup A$ as though it exists to presume an assumption is bounded above. And I'd argue that the sentence "doesn't apply" otherwise, rather than is "false".  That said though, I don't like the way the question was asked and I don't like your professors answers.

Actually, your professors are being dishonest.  To say $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$ is tacitly implying your universe is $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is certainly not bounded in $\mathbb R$.

I do not know which definitions have ben given in your class.
Apostol's " Mathematical Analysis" begins by defining the supremum for sets which are bounded above (Definition 1.13). In the sense of this definition you are right: $\sup$ is undefined for sets which are not bounded above.
However, just a little later Apostol introduces the extended real number system $\mathbb R^* = \mathbb R \cup \{ +\infty, -\infty\}$ (Chapter 1.20). He then writes

The principal reason for introducing the symbols $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ is one of convenience. For example, if we define $+\infty$ to be the sup of a set of real numbers which is not bounded above, then every nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ has a supremum in $\mathbb R^*$. The sup is finite if the set is bounded above and infinite if it is not bounded above.

In this sense your professor is right.
So what is the "correct" answer? It depends of the definition of the supremum.
I can only guess that in your class the  sup of a set of real numbers which is not bounded above was defined as $+\infty$, but of course I do not  know it. Anyway, Apostol is very clear concerning this point.

Thanks for your response, and I am totally aware of this. However, as detailly as I can recall, my prof did give us definition 1.13 while introducing $\mathbb{R}^*$ later but did not define sup $\mathbb{R}$ as $\infty$.

Also, even if sup $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as $\infty$, and by Apostol's word, it has a sup in $\mathbb{R}^$, I wonder whether the same set has a sup in $\mathbb{R}$? Since $\infty$ will have a meaning only in the context of $\mathbb{R}^$, but not in $\mathbb{R}$. For by my understanding of Apostol's context, defining this is simply a process to discuss case in $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Or there might be something I missed? When $\mathbb{R}$ is defined to have $\infty$ as its sup in $\mathbb{R}^*$, does it simultaneously mean sup $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

"When R is defined to have ∞ as its sup in R∗, does it simultaneously mean sup R is ∞ in R?" Absolutely not!  Just like $A = {q\in \mathbb Q|q^2 < 2}\subseteq \mathbb Q$ but $\sup A \not \in \mathbb Q$.  If $\mathbb R$ is bounded in $\mathbb R^*$ (but not in $\mathbb R$) we have $\sup \mathbb R\not \in \mathbb R$.  But to be honest, I don't really like your professors.  It's not universal to assume our universe is always extended number line. Quite the opposite really.  In my opinion you display the potential to eventually become a much better mathematician than they.
